# Transaction isolation level REPEATABLE READ causes deadlocks

Tags: sql-server, transactions

A part of my application updates a table as per business logic after opening a connection on transaction isolation level REPEATABLE READ. In a rare scenario, If this operation coincides with another part of the application which opens a different connection and tries to reset the same record to its default value. I get following error

```
Msg 1205, Level 13, State 45, Line 7
Transaction (Process ID 60) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
```

I think i am able to re-produce the issue using following example.

1.

```
create table Accounts
(
id int identity(1,1),
Name varchar(50),
Amount decimal
)
```

2.

```
insert into Accounts (Name,Amount) values ('ABC',5000)
insert into Accounts (Name,Amount) values ('WXY',4000)
insert into Accounts (Name,Amount) values ('XYZ',4500)
```

3.

Start a long transaction with isolation level as REPEATABLE READ

```
Set transaction isolation level REPEATABLE READ

begin tran

declare @var int

select @var=amount 
from Accounts
where id=1

waitfor delay '0:0:10'

if @var > 4000

update accounts 
set amount = amount -100;

Commit
```

4.

While Step.3 above is still being executed. Start another transaction on a different connection

```
Begin tran

update accounts
set Amount = 5000
where id = 1

commit tran
```

Transaction started in Step 3 would eventually complete but the one started in Step 4 would fail with following error message.

```
Msg 1205, Level 13, State 45, Line 7
Transaction (Process ID 60) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
```

What are my options to be able to eventually run transaction in step 4. The idea is to be able to reset the record to a default value and anything being performed on other transactions should be overridden in this case. I don't see any issue if both the transactions are not concurrent.

Comment: So `Account` table is a heap without any non-clustered index ?

Comment: For this re-pro example, its a heap but i have to check the actual table. Would this matter ?

Comment: Of course. It matters every indexes. Please add the list with all indexes on Account table.

Comment: Thanks @BogdanSahlean let me check indexes on table in question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The idea is to be able to reset the record to a default value

In what order do you want the updates applied? Do you want the "reset" to always come through? Then you need to perform the reset strictly after the update in step 3 has completed. Also, the reset update should use a higher lock mode to avoid the deadlock:

```
update accounts WITH (XLOCK)
set Amount = 5000
where id = 1
```

That way the reset will wait for the other transaction to finish first because the other tran has an S-lock.

Alternatively, habe step 3 acquire an U-lock or X-lock.

Comment: Thanks, This is exactly what i wanted. I tried your suggestion and it seems to be working as per the requirement. I am not sure if i understood what XLOCK is doing here. I read the doc http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx but could not relate to this scenario.

Comment: XLOCK makes the query acquire exclusive locks instead of U locks. You don't want the lock to be compatible with what step 3 does so that step 4 must wait for step 3 to finish.

Comment: Just realized one more thing, If only the transaction isolation level of Step 3 is changed to "SERIALIZABLE", its GRANTed the X lock (as seen in sys.dm_tran_locks) while Step 4  transaction WAITs for IX request_mode. This way Step 3 finishes and then Step 4 continues.

Comment: The X-LOCK that you are seeing from step 3 can only come from the (completed) update statement because serializable does not cause X-locking where previously only S-locking happened. Serializable actually only causes more S-locks and causes those locks to be held longer. Btw, add a clustered index on `id` to your example so that row locking can be used. Right now you might see artifacts from table locking (the table is a heap that must always be scanned).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the deadlock priority of transaction in setp 4 to be higher
For more details see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186736.aspx

Comment: That will make step 4 succeed but kill the other tran.