# Dead lock while using Repeatable Read Isolation level sql

Tags: c#, sql

Recently my team done a project on asp.net c# . It is to add the features to the exisiting project which is done by some other company.

Its a shopping cart. When the user places an order in very rare cases we are running into dead lock situation and the Database connections are being completely lost which are established through entripise library

> Error : Transaction (Process ID 89) was deadlocked on lock resources
>   with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun
>   the transaction.

So we searched for various reasons for the occurance of dead lock finally we came to know the exact reaosn for the dead lock

Reason :

```
DBWrapper wrapper = new DBWrapper(true,System.Data.IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead);
```

Using of **IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead** causing the dead lock issue.

So I have bit poor knowledge on Locks concept in sql.

Expected sloutions:

1) Plan is to change the isolation level which will be similar behaviour to **IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead** and prevent dead lock occurance.

2) Or else keeping the same isolation level in the code and make sql query with any lock 
concept and make it work successful.

Please its a high priority issue for us...  Your thoughts will be highly appreciated.

Please suggest me what to do for my expected solution.

Comment: Do you need to use Repeatable Read? Can you not use Read Committed? My suggestion is read the following: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx

Comment: I think this can help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557782/transaction-isolation-level-repeatable-read-causes-deadlocks

Comment: The isolation level is only part of the problem. The queries are what actually deadlock. The question does not have any information about them. As it stands nothing useful can be answered.